# Remove Extra Whitespace Surrounding Iframe

Tags: iframe, removing-whitespace

I'm a noob in code, trying to remove the extra white space of an iframe generated by Maillet provider. I think it's something simple but I've not enough knowledge, all my attempts are failure.

On one hand I've the Html code to design the email form, on the other hand the iframe code generated by mailjet after customizing the form (that I include into my website builder Adobe Muse).

Here the Html code of the form :

```
<div class="mj-embedded mj-embed-shadow mj-vertical" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Ubuntu, Helvetica; line-height: normal; text-align: left; background-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; padding: 20px; width: 280
                                                        px; height: 150px;">
<div class="mj-embedded-content" style="padding: 15px; background-color: transparent; box-shadow: none;">
    <div class="mj-embedded-header" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 26px; max-width: 100%; width: auto; color: rgb(89, 91, 97);"> </div>
```

**SEND**

```
</div>
```

Here the Iframe code generated:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://app.mailjet.com/widget/iframe/rxk/5OV" width="100%" height="150"></iframe>
```

Thanks a lot, I'll be so happy if you could help me, working alone at home, not always easy :)

Comment: Have you looked at this in the Chrome Inspector tools (or likewise for other browsers)? That usually helps find where the whitespace is coming from and can guide you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks iHowell, issue solved :)